# Eliminating a space in concatenated values when null

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SELECT statement reads something like this:

`SELECT JKLL.LKJJ, LKJF.ASLKD, TRIM (ADDR.UNNBR) || ' ' || TRIM(ADDR.PREDIR) || ' ' ||, TRIM(ADDR.STREET)`....

Where UNNBR is the address number and PREDIR is the predirection (NSEW).

When concatenating into the same column, if predir is null, I get two spaces between UNNBR and STREET, obviously.

Can I use a case statement to eliminate this space when PREDIR is null? If so, what would that syntax look like?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? The syntax varies between them.

Comment: you should use sql `COALESCE`

Comment: Oh sorry. SQL Server

Comment: `||` is the Oracle concatenation operator, SQL Server is `+`... are you sure you're using SQL Server?

Comment: FYI, [tag:sql] is not the tag for SQL Server. Use [tag:sql-server] for that.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes do something like this for these situations:

(TSQL syntax)

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN ADDR.UNNBRIS IS NOT NULL THEN ADDR.UNNBR + ' ' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN ADDR.PREDIR IS NOT NULL THEN ADDR.PREDIR + ' ' ELSE '' END + 
...
```

This way you only get the space if the field isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ISNULL`

```
SELECT JKLL.LKJJ, LKJF.ASLKD, TRIM(ADDR.UNNBR) + ISNULL(' ' + TRIM(ADDR.PREDIR),'') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A `NULL` value concatenated to anything yields a `NULL`. So something like this will work:

```
WITH ex as
    (SELECT 'Pants' as item, null as other, 'George' as name)
SELECT COALESCE(item + ' ', '')  
    + COALESCE(other + ' ', '')  
    + COALESCE(name + ' ', '')  
FROM ex
```

Comment: That just going to change his NULL values to blanks.  He'll still end up with two spaces in a row if the field is empty.

Comment: I can see  what it does just by looking at the code...but to humor you, when the query is run, you get this:

    `Pants  George`

There are two spaces there.  EDIT - Apparently one of the spaces is getting removed when I post the comment (derned HTML).  There are two spaces though.

Comment: @Jim, yeah, I was not thinking clearly (immediately deleted my previous comment upon posting it). Answer edited.